# Generate several random numbers, one of which must be the correct answer to a sum?

Tags: random, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have created a Space Invaders game in which the player must shoot an asteroid which displays a random number.  A sum will also be randomly generated at the start of the scene.  Once the player shoots an asteroid the scene reloads, with points awarded for correct answers.

The problem I am having is that I need at least one asteroid to display the correct answer. I am currently achieving this by reloading the scene until an asteroids number matches the answer to the sum.  This can take quite a few reloads and looks really bad.  Is there a better way to achive this which will look better and be more efficient. I have included my effort below. I appreciate any comments. Thanks!

Script for checking the correct answer and reloading the scene.

```
#pragma strict

function Start ()
{

}

{

    if (
        Asteroid1_Script.asteroid1Value != (Sum_Script.sumA - Sum_Script.sumB) &&
        Asteroid2_Script.asteroid2Value != (Sum_Script.sumA - Sum_Script.sumB) &&
        Asteroid3_Script.asteroid3Value != (Sum_Script.sumA - Sum_Script.sumB) &&       
        Asteroid4_Script.asteroid4Value != (Sum_Script.sumA - Sum_Script.sumB) &&
        Asteroid5_Script.asteroid5Value != (Sum_Script.sumA - Sum_Script.sumB) 
        )

    {
        Application.LoadLevel("L1");
    }
}
```

Script for randomly generating the sum.

```
#pragma strict

static var sumA :int = 0;
static var sumB :int = 0;

function Start () 
{
    var newSumA = Random.Range(6,10);
    sumA = newSumA;
    var newSumB = Random.Range(1,6);
    sumB = newSumB;

}

function Update () {
    //Question Output.

    guiText.text = sumA.ToString() + " - " + sumB.ToString()+ " =";
}
```

Script for generating an asteroids random number.

```
#pragma strict

var mainCam: Camera;
static var asteroid1Value : int = 0;
var asteroid1 : Transform;
var Asteroid1Style : GUIStyle; 

function Start () 
{
    var newAsteroid1Value = Random.Range(0,10);

    asteroid1Value = newAsteroid1Value;

    asteroid1.position.x = mainCam.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector3 (160f, 0f, 0f)).x;
    asteroid1.position.y = mainCam.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector3 (0f, 450f, 0f)).y;

}

function OnGUI()
{
    var point = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
    GUI.Label(new Rect(point.x, Screen.currentResolution.height - point.y - 530, 110, 100), asteroid1Value.ToString(), Asteroid1Style); 
}

function OnCollisionEnter(col : Collision)
{

    if(asteroid1Value == (Sum_Script.sumA - Sum_Script.sumB))
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        Score_Script.score ++;   
    }
    if(asteroid1Value != (Sum_Script.sumA - Sum_Script.sumB))
    {
        Score_Script.score --;
    }

}
```

Comment: That's not javascript, is it?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just have 4 random asteroids and one with the right answer instead of 5 random?

Comment: @Bergi Looks like "[unityscript](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/UnityScript_versus_JavaScript)" is very javascript-like and often confused.

Comment: @JamesMontagne or UnrealScript...  (though I think you're right on this one.)

Answer (score 1):

Do as you are doing, generate 5 random numbers for your asteroids.

Then generate a random number between 1 and 5, this is your random asteroid, and then set its value to the answer. (sumA - sumB)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to abstract your logic.

The best argument I can make is, simply put, build your random numbers *before* you build your asteroids.

That way, you always have a correct one.

I would simply code:

```
function start(){  
    var x = 5 //X being whatever number of asteroids you wish.
    var a = new Array();
    for(var i=0; i<x; i++){ 
        a[i] = Random.Range(0,10);
    }

    for( i in a){ buildAsteroid(a[i]) }
 }
```

And... if the number matches, success.